# Create dataframe out of wordscore predictions

Tags: r, dataframe, quanteda

I have a problem with an R-exercise I'm doing. Namely, I need to recreate a dataframe from a study that has to do with wordscores.

I can recreate the wordscore predictions with

```
new_prediction <- predict(wordscores, textscores_dfm, rescaling = "lbg",
            interval = "confidence", 
            level = 0.95)
```

Which then gives me this (an excerpt):

```
$fit
                                          fit          lwr          upr
Afghanistan                       1.566180131  0.824737764  2.307622498
Angola                           -1.698743875 -2.414450695 -0.983037054
Albania                           0.852421377  0.171859062  1.532983692
Andorra                          -1.385334148 -1.989187448 -0.781480847
United Arab Emirates             -0.563616744 -1.174414840  0.047181352
Argentina                         0.874514416  0.190652482  1.558376350
Armenia                           0.105546272 -0.745004473  0.956097018
```

The problem is, the only column in new_prediction is $fit, while I would like to have fit, lwr, upr and year also in the dataframe (I could add the year later).

So, how do I go from the results into creating a neat dataframe with the results?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

The results so far can be recreated by running this:

```
library(quanteda)
library(quanteda.corpora)

docvars(data_corpus_ungd2017, "refscore") <-
  ifelse(docvars(data_corpus_ungd2017, "country") == "Russia", -1,
         ifelse(docvars(data_corpus_ungd2017, "country")== "United States", 1, NA))

textscores_dfm <- dfm(data_corpus_ungd2017, remove_punct = TRUE, 
                      remove_numbers = TRUE,
                      remove_symbols = TRUE,
                      remove_hyphens = TRUE) %>% 
  dfm_remove(stopwords("english")) %>% 
  dfm_wordstem(language = quanteda_options("language_stemmer"))


wordscores <- textmodel_wordscores(textscores_dfm, docvars(textscores_dfm, "refscore"))

new_prediction <- predict(wordscores, textscores_dfm, rescaling = "lbg",
                interval = "confidence", 
                level = 0.95)
```

Comment: What is `data_corpus_ungd2017`?

Comment: data_corpus_ungd2017 is a corpus that is available in the quanteda.corpora package.

Comment: Where do you download this package from? I cannot.

Comment: It is unclear your needs. Other than *year* aren't you showing us the data frame (maybe matrix) you require with *fit*, *lwr*, and *upr*? The data is just stored inside another object: `new_prediction$fit`.

Comment: Ah sorry I forgot it's not on CRAN, here you go:


devtools::install_github("quanteda/quanteda.corpora")

Answer (score 0):

Easy, since the years are stored inside the dfm as docvars.  You can extract them and cbind them to a new data.frame from the predictions.

Here I've also "tidy"ed up the data.frame to remove rownames, etc.

```
df <- data.frame(
    country = rownames(new_prediction$fit),
    year = docvars(textscores_dfm, "year"), 
    new_prediction$fit,
    row.names = NULL,
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

head(df)
##                country year        fit        lwr         upr
## 1          Afghanistan 2017  1.5659848  0.8253661  2.30660354
## 2               Angola 2017 -1.6880589 -2.4014488 -0.97466902
## 3              Albania 2017  0.8657384  0.1842963  1.54718058
## 4              Andorra 2017 -1.4177941 -2.0255257 -0.81006249
## 5 United Arab Emirates 2017 -0.5676109 -1.1787734  0.04355162
## 6            Argentina 2017  0.8507219  0.1586331  1.54281060
```